# Finance options for a new furnace.

Tags: united-states, loans, rent

Can I get a loan from a finance company and then purchase a new furnace and a/c unit for my home? If so, how does that work?

Comment: I'd imagine you would want to look at a Home Equity Line of Credit (HELOC), it's probably a significantly lower rate.  You may also be able to finance through the vendor selling you the appliances.

Comment: Do you own your home?  Is there a mortgage?  What's the status?  Almost paid off?  Barely started?  How much equity do you have?

Comment: Why did you use the "rent" tag?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, unless you get a loan for a specific purpose (car loan, mortgage) you can use the money for anything you feel like.

Comment: There is always the 100% down plan.

Comment: Massachusetts has [financing programs](http://www.masssave.com/financing) for improving energy efficiency.  Check to see if your state has something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You walk into the finance company with a written quote from the supplier for the equipment you want to buy. You then fill out forms and sign a promissory note. The finance company then writes out a check to the supplier for the amount of the quoted equipment. Usually you need to provide at least 3 things:

- ID such as a driver's license or passport
- proof of residency, such as a copy of your lease or a utility bill
- proof of employment such as a W-2 from your employer or a recent pay stub

They will require you to provide your social security number and sign a document allowing them to check your credit history which they will look up using the social security number.

Note that banks will generally give better rates on a personal loan than a finance company. People usually only use finance companies when their credit is so bad that a bank will not loan them money.

---

Heating and cooling companies that provide equipment will often loan the money to buy that equipment.

---

As a point of advice, it is generally poor financial management to take out personal loans and may indicate a person that is wasting money or be in financial difficulties. For personal loan items (furniture, cars, clothing, jewelry, etc) you are far better off saving money to buy the item, not borrowing beyond your means. If you need a new furnace and it is an emergency, for example, if it were winter (which it is not) and your furnace could not be repaired, then that might justifiable. But borrowing money at a high rate to just upgrade a furnace or get a luxury like AC is unwise.

Comment: Sound advice, though I would note that an A/C is only a luxury in some parts of the country; in others it is a necessity (areas that get over 100°F particularly with high humidity regularly).

Comment: People in those areas didn't live in the kind of apartments, condos, and houses that we now build knowing that we can air condition.  Large high density condos get *very* warm, particularly when they're insulated in ways that are very helpful in the winter but not always in the summer.  People still die today during heat waves, and it's generally people without A/C...